# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection when using sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sidekiq

We are unable to scale the frequency of our crons as we've would've liked and the thing holding us back is the number of database connection issues.

We have a primary server which has the master db, and 3 slaves. We run sidekiq on all our machines.

Our postgresql.conf  -: max_connections = 200

Our pool option is also set at pool: 200 on all our rails app - database.yml in our servers.
We are running 2 sidekiq processes on each of our servers

[image: Server Setup]

*In the green machine, if we change our concurrency from 6 to 7, we start getting a steam of errors -: Sidekiq - could not obtain a database connection within 5.042 seconds.* Where am I messing up? :-(

Could it be something else inside our app? The numbers just don't add up.

Also does the number of active record connections have any association with pg_stat_activity?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out

We're using replication, and in shards.yml, we had not set the pool size :-(

It was picking up 5 by default.